# How to find a google API's URL to return a WSDL?

Tags: google-api, business-objects, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

Hi there I am looking to use the google geocode API as a web service on Business Objects Data Services. It requires me to find a webservice URL in order specify the location of the external web service to accept a connection and return WSDL. I am looking to call the web service server at the indicated WSDL URL and obtain a list of the published services and port. Does anyone know how to locate that URL.

Comment: Are you talking about the google maps geocoding URL? In that case it is `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters` . You can see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index) for more info.

Comment: I am however Im not looking to make a request I am looking to call the web service server at the indicated WSDL URL and obtain a list of the
published services and ports.

Comment: From what I have seen, Google maps isn't a SOAP service so I don't think there is a WDSL. Here are some threads on Google that might help you [thread1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/HlslK3MB2K8) [thread2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api-web-services/RAVYixiGMkA)